# How to stop displaying title of next and privous article in my current article?

Tags: ee2, next-prev

i am using following code for display title of next and previous article in current article detail page

```
          {exp:channel:prev_entry}
            {exp:channel:entries channel="teaching_tips" dynamic="off" limit="1" sort="desc"}
            <p> &laquo; Previous Article: <a href="{url_title}">{title}</a></p>
            {/exp:channel:entries}
            {/exp:channel:prev_entry} 

            {exp:channel:next_entry}
            {exp:channel:entries channel="teaching_tips" dynamic="off" limit="1" sort="desc"}
            <p>Next Article: <a href="{url_title}">{title}</a> &raquo; </p>
            {/exp:channel:entries}       
            {/exp:channel:next_entry}
```

now i want to display only title of next and previous article which have same channel ="teaching_tips" but this code is display another channel entries how to stop this ?

and i want to display next article link when i will open 1st entry and when i will open last entry i want to display only previous article link how this i can do this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to remove the channel entries loops you have stuck within the next entry and previous entry tags - they themselves should contain the channel parameter:

```
{exp:channel:prev_entry channel="teaching_tips"}
   <p> &laquo; Previous Article: <a href="{url_title}">{title}</a></p>
{/exp:channel:prev_entry} 

{exp:channel:next_entry channel="teaching_tips"}
   <p>Next Article: <a href="{url_title}">{title}</a> &raquo; </p>
{/exp:channel:next_entry}
```

Like the entries loop itself, the pref_entry and next_entry tags, in absence of a channel parameter, will load from all channels.